# Can't get an example for React useMutationObserver hook to run

Tags: reactjs

I need to check the mutation of an react component in my app that I am developing. So I looked around for solutions for that and found this example. To learn how it works I am trying to implement it in my own app: https://www.30secondsofcode.org/react/s/use-mutation-observer

I have created a blank new React app but I can't get it to run like it does in the codepen provided on the site.

1st. `ref` is missing as a dependency in the useEffect hook, so I added it.

2nd. It does nothing, it updates the text output in `<p>{content}</p>` but it keeps staying on `mutationCount: 0`

Here my App.js

```
import React from "react";

const useMutationObserver = (
  ref,
  callback,
  options = {
    attributes: true,
    characterData: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
  }
) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(ref.current, options);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [callback, options, ref]); //added ref here
};

const App = () => {
  const mutationRef = React.useRef();
  const [mutationCount, setMutationCount] = React.useState(0);
  const incrementMutationCount = () => {
    return setMutationCount(mutationCount + 1);
  };
  useMutationObserver(mutationRef, incrementMutationCount);
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState('Hello world');

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="content-input">Edit this to update the text:</label>
      <textarea
        id="content-input"
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        value={content}
        onChange={e => setContent(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        ref={mutationRef}
      >
        <div
          style={{
            resize: 'both',
            overflow: 'auto',
            maxWidth: '100%',
            border: '1px solid black',
          }}
        >
          <h2>Resize or change the content:</h2>
          <p>{content}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Mutation count {mutationCount}</h3>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

What is different in my app?

Comment: Does it throw any console errors? The pen example is using 2 outside react scripts and you should make sure you are using the same version:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js

And it's using babel as a pre-processor

Comment: There was an error on the console when I copied the code from the blog about <label for=, I corrected it to htmlFor. But I am sure that this is unrelated to the problem that the callback is not ran on MutationObserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new instance of `callback` and `options` is created every time `App` component re-renders, making the useEffect callback function running on every change. You can remove them from the dependency list and make sure that useEffect block will run after component is mounted or if `ref` changes only:

```
const useMutationObserver = (
  ref,
  callback,
  options = {
    CharacterData: true,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true,
  }
) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
      observer.observe(ref.current, options);
      return () => observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [ref]);
};
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-crgbjj?file=src%2FApp.js)

Another solution is to keep `callback` and `options` reference with no changes.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand your answer 100%. What did you mean by "Another solution is to keep callback and options reference with no changes." If I copy and paste your example into my app it works but I get exhaustive debs warning. When I add callback and options to the array, it stops working. So it only works with the warning. (I could suppress it but is that proper?)

Comment: You can wrap `incrementMutationCount` in `useCallback` hook to keep the function reference and then add the `useMutationObserver` callback in the `useEffect` dependency list. For keeping `options` reference you could use `useRef`, but if you are sure that running the `useEffect` callback when component is mounted only is enough for your use case, use `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` to disable those warnings.